# I want a user group with team lead in drupal. Any modules I want to assaign a user in to a team

Tags: drupal

Any module available in drupal-7 to assign users in team? Team Lead can able to see information about him team members node

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on the same scenario in one of my project, but at that time I achieved this by using following modules:

- [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)
- [Custom Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_perms)

and adding referencing fields in user, some custom code and hooks.

Later on I used [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module and it's also pretty good.

As you are looking for some modules which can do the same for you are is one Organic group and other one is [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group).

Many extra features you will get with these modules.